# Why ex (vim) is catching matching pattern to the end of line

Tags: regex, vim, ex

File contains following line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Bash script that replaces one version to another:

```
echo "%s/AssemblyVersion\s*\(.*\)/AssemblyVersion(\"$newVersionNumber\")]/g
        w
        q
        " | ex $filePath
```

The question is why this catch whole line to the end so i have to add `]` at the end of replacement string?

Comment: It is because `.*` matches all the chars to the end, replace it with `[^]]*` and you won't have to add `]` in the replacement.

Comment: Is this a greedy regex that doesn't stop at `)`?

Comment: Yes, `.*` and `[^]]*` are greedy since `*` is a greedy quantifier, and they both match `)`, but `.` matches any char, and `[^]]` matches any char but `]`.

Comment: Hmm, If `.*` catches the `)` then what is happening with `)` explicitly specified in the regex?

Comment: I think you wanted to match `(` with `\(` and `)` with `\)`, right? That is not so in Vim. Unescape the `(` and `)` to match literal parentheses.

Comment: Thanks it works! Wrong usage of capture groups in vim. Would you like to answer the question and take the credit?

Comment: I've already posted answer :) and added a shorter alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because `.*` matches all the chars to the end of the line, and `\(` and `\)` create a *capturing group* (unlike most of NFA regex engines, Vim regex matches a `(` char with an unescaped `(` and `)` with an unescaped `)` in the pattern).

You may use

```
%s/AssemblyVersion\s*([^()]*)/AssemblyVersion(\"$newVersionNumber\")/g
```

Here, `AssemblyVersion` will match the word, then `\s*` will match any 0+ whitespace chars, `(` will match a literal `(`, `[^()]*` will match 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, and `)` will match a literal `)`.

Another regex substitution command you may use is

```
:%s/AssemblyVersion\s*(\zs[^()]*\ze)/\"$newVersionNumber\"/g
```

Here, `AssemblyVersion\s*(` will match `AssemblyVersion`, 0+ whitespaces and `(` and `\zs` will omit that part from the match, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` will get matched, and then `\ze)` will check if there is `)` to the right of the current location, but won't add it to the match.

`\zs` sets the next character to be the first character of the match. Any text before the `\zs` pattern will not be included into the match.

`\ze` sets the end of the match. Anything after the `\zs` pattern will not be part of the match.